# flask_mysqldb - MYSQL cursor is throwing an error - cursor is not a known member of "None"

Tags: python, flask

I am writing a simple auth service in python using **`flask`** and **`flask_mysqldb`**. There is an error with the cursor.

```py
import jwt
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

server = Flask(__name__)

mysql = MySQL(server)

# server configuration 
server.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = os.environ.get("MYSQL_HOST")
server.config["MYSQL_USER"] = os.environ.get("MYSQL_USER")
server.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] = os.environ.get("MYSQL_PASSWORD")
server.config["MYSQL_DB"] = os.environ.get("MYSQL_DB")
server.config["MYSQL_PORT"] = os.environ.get("MYSQL_PORT")

# print(server.config["MYSQL_HOST"])
# print(server.config["MYSQL_PORT"])

@server.route("/login", methods=["POST"])

def login():
    auth = request.authorization
    if not auth:
        return "missing credentials",401

    #check db for username and password
    
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    res = cur.execute(
        "SELECT email,password FROM user WHERE email=%s, (auth.username)"
    )
```

[image: Error]

This works on a virtual environment. All the specified packages are correctly installed.

Answer (score 1):

Please try
cur = mysql.connect.cursor()
if you use a connection it will not suggest cursor(). once you use connect.cursor() it will not show the error. Thanks